# Jquery поиск и удаление текста в строке

Tags: javascript

**Код:**

```
var text = 'This is a little, small text.';
var texttoremove = 'small';
var result = text.replace(texttoremove, '');
console.log(result);
```

Выведет: This is a little,  text.

Как сделать так, чтобы при наличии запятой слева она тоже удалялась, и при отсутствии, оной, удалялся только текст.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [регулярным выражением](https://learn.javascript.ru/regular-expressions-javascript):

```js
const texttoremove = 'small';
const regexp = new RegExp(',?\\s+'+texttoremove);
console.log(
'This is a little, small text.'.replace(regexp, ''),
'This is a little small text.'.replace(regexp, '')
);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а как вставить место 'small' переменную?

Comment: Второй аргумент replace - это то, на что вы заменяте

Comment: Все верно, но переменную нужно вставить именно в регулярное выражение.

Comment: @Bareza обновил ответ

Comment: Большое спасибо!